# Cycle through rows containing dates on a monthly basis

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to perform a "sumif and countif" conditional loop against a dynamic range.

If either of the conditions are met a response is provided to an adjacent "Output" cell of each row and then the loop goes on across each row of the range until completion.

The table/spreadsheets contain repeating products and various values often at a certain date. The code below works but is only 50% of what I want.

I want to apply a secondary loop which applies the above first loop's calculations against data at 30 day or monthly increments e.g., the countif and sumif loop is applied only to rows between January 1st 2020 and January 31st 2020 rather than the entire range (starting from the minimum date in the range).
Then the loop goes on to e.g., February 1st 2020 to February 28th 2020 or the next 30 days after the first 30 days and does the calculation again. The dates often repeat for each row of data which make things slightly more complicated.

Example data:

```
Date        ||    Changing_Price    ||      Product    ||      Output
11/16/2019         $23                     Apple              Too large
11/16/2019         $50                     Apple              Too large
11/17/2019         $23                     Apple              Too large
11/21/2019         $10                     Orange             Too large
11/16/2019         $5                      Orange             Too large
11/21/2019         $5                      Orange             Too large
11/21/2019         $5                      Orange             Too large
12/23/2019         $23                     Apple              Buy
12/23/2019         $20                     Apple              Buy
```

```vb
Sub Macro_1

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'variables
Dim rngCriteria As Range
Dim rngSum As Range  
Set rngCriteria = Range (“M2:M200”) 
Set rngSum = Range (“L2:L200”)
Dim rngResult As Long
Dim rngResult2 As Long
Dim cell As Range

'Loop to perform countif and sumif 
For Each cell In Worksheets(“Sheet1”).Range(“N2:N200”)
    rngResult = WorksheetFunction.SumIf (rngCriteria, cell.Offset (0,-1).Value, rngSum)
    rngResult2 = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(rngCriteria, cell.Offset (0,-1).Value)
    If rngResult > 50 Or rngResult2 >2
        cell = “Too large”
    Else
        Cell = “Buy”
    End If
Next cell

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: "sumif and countif" ? Where is the CountIf ?

Comment: @CDP1802 - thanks for highlighting the typo, I have changed the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `SumIfs` and `CountIfs` and add in date range criteria.

```vb
Sub Macro_1()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'variables
    Dim rngCriteria As Range, rngDate As Range, rngSum As Range
    Dim cell As Range, lastrow As Long
     
    Dim vSum As Double, vCount As Long
    Dim dt1 As Date, dt2 As Date
    Dim m As Long, y As Long, prd As String
    
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngDate = .Range("K2:K" & lastrow)
        Set rngSum = .Range("L2:L" & lastrow)
        Set rngCriteria = .Range("M2:M" & lastrow)
       
        'Loop to perform countif and sumif
        For Each cell In rngDate
        
            m = Month(cell)
            y = Year(cell)
            dt1 = DateSerial(y, m, 1)
            dt2 = DateAdd("m", 1, dt1) ' 1 month on
            
            prd = cell.Offset(, 2).Value2 ' colM
            
            vSum = WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(rngSum, rngCriteria, prd, _
                     rngDate, ">=" & CLng(dt1), _
                     rngDate, "<" & CLng(dt2))
                     
            vCount = WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rngCriteria, prd, _
                     rngDate, ">=" & CLng(dt1), _
                     rngDate, "<" & CLng(dt2))
                     
            ' Outout col N
            If vSum > 50 Or vCount > 2 Then
               cell.Offset(, 3) = "Too large"
            Else
                cell.Offset(, 3) = "Buy"
            End If
                     
            ' for checking
            cell.Offset(, 5) = vSum
            cell.Offset(, 6) = vCount
            cell.Offset(, 7) = Format(dt1, "d/m/yy")
            cell.Offset(, 8) = Format(dt2, "d/m/yy")
           
        Next cell
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```